# SQLAlchemy DateTime to datetime.datetime

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

How do you make comparisons between DateTime fields and datetime.datetime objects in SQLAlchemy queries?

For instance, if I do

```
candidates = session.query(User).filter_by((User.time - datetime.datetime.utcnow()) > datetime.timedelta(months=2))
```

I will get

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'DateTime' and 'datetime.datetime'
```

I'm guessing this is because the DateTime field is never fully extracted when we use the filter_by command, hence it is not coverted to a datetime.datetime object? Is this correct? How do SQLAlchemy users generally handle this?

Note: User.time is a DateTime field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, notice that datetime.timedelta does not take 'months' as an argument. Try it with 'weeks=8' instead (http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta).

Second, use 'filter' rather than 'filter_by' as the latter is for simpler queries involving queries by value (i.e. User.name='Bob' http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter).

So, what I would write would look like this:

```
candidates = session.query(User).filter((User.time - datetime.datetime.utcnow()) > datetime.timedelta(weeks=8))
```

And finally, what is the mapping of your 'User' table, maybe the problem is with the Columns definitions?